# Why does Prisma say unknown argument when nested create relation?

Tags: prisma

I have this schema in Prisma:

```
model Job{
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  profile Profile @relation(fields: [profileId],references: [id])
  profileId Int
  skills String[] @default([])
  slug String
  name String @default("Edit me")
  description String @default("")
  messages Message[]
  isActive Boolean @default(false)
  channels  CommunicationChannel[]
}

model Profile {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [sub])
  userId String @unique
  username String @unique
  isHiring Boolean 
  skills String[] @default([])
  jobs Job[]
  description String @default("")
  title String @default("")
  channels CommunicationChannel[] 
  messagesFrom Message[] @relation("from")
  messagesTo Message[] @relation("to")
}

model CommunicationChannel {
  id      Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  profile Profile @relation(fields: [profileId], references: [id])
  profileId Int
  job     Job      @relation(fields: [jobId], references: [id])
  jobId   Int
}
```

and then I want to create a CommunicationChannel instance and connect it to a Profile instance. For this I do:

```
  await prisma.profile.update({
    where: { id: myId },
    include: { channels: true },
    data: {
      channels: {
        create: [
          {
            job: { connect: { id: jobId } },
            profile: { connect: { id } },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
```

But this fails with this message:

```
PrismaClientValidationError:
Invalid `prisma.profile.update()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    id: 1
  },
  include: {
    channels: true
  },
  data: {
    channels: {
      create: [
        {
          job: {
            connect: {
              id: 2
            }
          },
          profile: {
            connect: {
              id: 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Unknown argument `profile`.
```

If anyone can tell me what is wrong with this code and why is failing it will be very appreciated by me (and others googling it). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with this schema:

```
model Profile {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [sub])
  userId String @unique
  username String @unique
  isHiring Boolean 
  skills String[] @default([])
  jobs Job[]
  description String @default("")
  title String @default("")
  channelsOrigin CommunicationChannel[] @relation("fromProfile") 
  channelsDestination CommunicationChannel[] @relation("toProfile")
  messagesFrom Message[] @relation("from")
  messagesTo Message[] @relation("to")
}

model CommunicationChannel {
  id      Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  from Profile @relation("fromProfile", fields: [fromId], references: [id])
  fromId Int
  to Profile @relation("toProfile", fields: [toId], references: [id])
  toId Int
  job     Job      @relation(fields: [jobId], references: [id])
  jobId   Int
}
```

and this query:

```
  await prisma.communicationChannel.create({
    data: {
      job: { connect: { id: jobId } },
      to: { connect: { id } },
      from: { connect: { id: myId } },
    },
  });
```